# Cómo puedo insertar un salto de línea dentro de un Button Data-Toggle?

Tags: php, botón, salto-de-linea

estoy haciendo un popover con información en un botón desplegable.. el código es este...

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" 
data-toggle="popover" 
data-placement="right" 
data-content="<?php echo $elemento; ?> Línea: <?php echo $linea; ?> Fabricante: <?php echo $fabricante; ?> Foto Control: <?php echo $fotoControl; ?>" 
title="" 
data-original-title="Detalles de LED">Ver</button>
```

El resultado es un botón con los datos que tomé de la DB, pero no tiene saltos de línea... así se ve en pantalla...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven el texto está desordenado, deseo colocar saltos de línea entre cada característica, pero nada me funciona.

Gracias de antemano. Estoy seguro que debe ser algo muy sencillo pero lo desconozco.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar el salto de línea `<br />` convencional de `HTML`, pero adicionalmente debes agregar del atributo `data-bs-html="true"` para habilitar el uso de etiquetas `HTML` dentro del `popover`.

Te dejo un ejemplo completo con `bootstrap` 5. Si tu versión es diferente y no te funciona, revisa la documentación de tu versión.

```js
const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl))
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <br><br>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-content="<?php echo $elemento; ?> <br />Línea: <?php echo $linea; ?> <br />Fabricante: <?php echo $fabricante; ?> <br />Foto Control: <?php echo $fotoControl; ?>">Haz click para ver el popover</button>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hola @DjCrazy... gracias, perfecto... eso es... solo que mi versi´n es BT4 y la etiqueta es solo `date-html="true"`
Solucionado 100%